# Reset/restore/recover Windows 10 laptop to factory state

Tags: windows, drivers, windows-10, format

I would like your help with a problem I am stuck with. I recently got a hand-me-down HP ProBook 4530s that I upgraded from Windows 7 Pro x64 to Windows 10 via the "Get Windows 10" app that pops up (as did most of you, I presume). This laptop was a work laptop from my father's company and it contains files and folder that he would like me remove.

Now, what I would prefer to do is the old fashioned way of formatting the PC as I would have done, had I stayed with Windows 7. I know that Windows 10 has a feature, I believe it's called "Reset", which allows you to do [the following](http://kmpic.asus.com/images/2015/08/18/4fa81d32-0b55-406a-be96-a3396d35eacb.jpg).

The 2nd bullet says `Resetting will remove Any apps and programs that didn't come with this PC`. Does this mean that hardware drivers will be kept? This is my main problem. I would like to get rid of all my files and clean up my HDD, but by keeping all my drivers (because [HP's support site](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=5060881&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4059) has a ton of drivers for this specific laptop, and I'm far too lazy to download them all.)

I have tried to read up on Windows 10's added reset/restore/recover functionality, but can not seem to get a clear answer as to whether or not any of these options are what I am looking for. Apparently the `Reset` function is used when recycling a PC. Is that what I am doing?

Is there perhaps anyone on here that has a tried-and-tested solution for me? Or is what I am looking for non-existent?

Thanks a bunch for reading!

TL;DR: To format, or not to format?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 options when you Restore your PC, none of them remove all drivers, only ones that were installed by you so factory drivers will remain. These options become available after the restore process is started.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-10-recovery-options)

[image]